# get the first day of each month between two dates in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, datastep

I would like to perform a cycle between two dates considering only the first day of each month between the selected dates.

My starting point is the following script:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
end_date   = datetime.date(2020, 4, 4)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

while start_date <= end_date:

    print(start_date)

    start_date += delta
```

It works when I choose:

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

but it gives me an error when I try to select "months" as delta time.
Could some one give a glue on this.

This is the solution that I set-up following the suggestions reported bellow:

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)

end_date = datetime.date(2020, 4, 4)


datenow = start_date

while datenow <= end_date:

    y,m     = divmod(datenow.year*12+datenow.month,12)
    datenow = datetime.date(y,m+1,1)
    print(datenow)
```

Comment: timedelta doesn't support months, it goes up to days.
You can simply add 31 days as your timedelta and manually set the day for each date to the first day. You will not be able to go out of range since you are always interested in the first of each month. Loop over the `range(start_date.month, end_date.month+1)` and set the days within.

Comment: Have a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353919/how-can-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-next-month-in-python