# How to get the next month in Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework, ui-automation

I am trying to print the next month in roboframework and wrote something like this:

${actual_current_date_t}=        Get Current Date    result_format=%b %Y
${actual_next_date}=    Add Time To Date  ${actual_current_date_t}  31 days    result_format=%b %Y

log to console    ${actual_next_date}

But not able to print it. Desired Output : Feb 2023

Answer (score 0):

Adding time to date can be dangerous in this case because some months are shorter than 31 days and this would cause the code to skip a month. This question has some excellent answers, and it's easy to convert it to RF: [How can I get the first day of the next month in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353919/how-can-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-next-month-in-python)

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DateTime

Next Month
    ${new_date}=  Evaluate    (datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=1)+datetime.timedelta(days=32))
    ${next_m}=    Convert Date   ${x}    result_format=%b %Y
```