# How to set the date to 1st of next month with a timezone python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

We want to set the date to the first of next month in a particular timezone. For example if the timezone is "America/Los Angeles", we want to set the date to 9/1/2023. The current date is 8/15/2023. We have tried various options like the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353919/how-can-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-next-month-in-python).

```
 current_datetime_tz = current_datetime.replace(tzinfo=timezone)
 next_month = (current_datetime_tz.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)
 next_month_timestamp = int(next_month.timestamp())
```

But we don't get the right answer. The next_month timestamp we get is 1693546186. This is Thursday, August 31, 2023 10:29:46 PM GMT-07:00 DST. We were expecting Friday September 1, 2023 0:0:0am GMT -7:00 DST.

Please help.

Comment: What are you using for `timezone`?  If it comes from `pytz` you can't just use `replace` on it, that doesn't work.

Comment: You aren't going to get `0:0:0` unless you replace `hour`, `minute`, and `second` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method to get the current time with a timezone attached.  Using `replace` isn't reliable; do this instead:

```
current_datetime_tz = datetime.datetime.now(timezone)
```

And then it's not enough to replace just the day, you need to replace all the lesser parts too.

```
next_month = (current_datetime_tz.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

P.S. I like your technique of replacing the day and then adding 32 days, I wouldn't have thought of that.